# How do I use Jade & Angular for a MEAN stack app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

I am new to learning how to build using the MEAN stack and I am at a point where I have my app themed using the jade template engine on top of Express 4. The next step is to build the angular piece of the app and I am confused on one point - why do I need to use two template engines here?

I'd really like to know if it's necessary to use jade and angular together (if so what the optimal setup there is), or just one or the other (if so why?). Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Jade is what renders the stuff sent to the browser. Angular is a client-side framework, it's not a template engine. You could render the initial Angular view via Jade; it has to be made *somehow*, after all.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was reading through some repos that are built on angular and express and I saw that they don't use jade at all and more so "ejs" to render html files that are pure html/angular. Could you explain why?

Comment: Because some people prefer EJS over Jade?

Comment: @DaveNewton what would be the reason to combine Jade & Angular (maybe using Jade partials for example)?

Comment: Because the initial view may come from the server side. *Something* has to load the browser with the initial HTML, no? That could come from a CDN, the server (e.g., via Jade), static resources, etc.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So if my root "app.js" file that contains the Express code loads before the static HTML template, I assume this would cause a blank page to display or slow load. If I have Jade running, I can serve the page as soon as its requested, then load remaining things using static html/Angular. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're saying. The browser has to make a request before it will display *anything*, otherwise... what would it even display? The browser ("client") makes a request to your app. Your app sends something back: for the first page load it needs to send back HTML. *How* that HTML is generated is irrelevant. *Then* there might be more stuff happening "behind the scenes", e.g., Ajax via AngularJS or whatever.

Comment: (I'm ignoring pre-loading initial data to prevent the appearance of an unpopulated template, which is a bit more advanced than where we seem to be at the moment.)

Comment: To clarify @DaveNewton I was asking if using Jade, would allow me to serve a page that loaded faster since it is being executed on the Node server with all the dynamic content already in place - I assume if I did that on Angular, it'd wait for the server to finish loading the content so the user may see parts of the page that are incomplete. We are both talking about preventing the user from seeing a blank page or components after the initial request.